# Can't assign RoutedEvent to Binding.TargetUpdated

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

I have a textblock which should react for changing its text (it must display text for few seconds, and then dissapear).

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OperationMessage, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" x:Name="label_OperationMessage" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3,3,3,3" >
                 <TextBlock.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0" To="1.0" />
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:5" />
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
</TextBlock.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
```

When I launch my app I get error :

```
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'.
```

on the line

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only event supported by Silverlight for use in the `Triggers` property is the `Loaded` event.  Anything else will result in this exception.

To acheive this sort of Xaml event logic you can download the Blend SDK which contains all manner of useful features like this.  In your case you are looking for the `PropertyChangedTrigger`.